# Image not setting in ImageView after taking picture from Camera

Tags: android, uri, android-camera, android-imageview

I've have develop my own camera app for mandatory configuration, when i try to show the captured image in next activity which displays whether to save it or not?

I'm not able to fetch the image which i captured and displays on my <kbd>ImageView</kbd>. I'm absolutely getting `absPathUri` with proper path.

Code snippets:-

```
imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picView);
Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();
absPathUri = Uri.parse(b.getString("URI"));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+absPathUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(absPathUri!=null)
{
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));
    imgView.setImageURI(absPathUri);
}
```

On Further dive in the reason why I'm unable to set the <kbd>ImageView</kbd>, throws the `Null Pointer Exception` which is due to `File Not Found`. If applicatoin is in debug mode it displays the proper Image on <kbd>ImageView</kbd>. It seems that mediaStore get Refreshed till the debugging hits.

```
File imgFile = new  File(getPath(absPathUri));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ImageFile Exists"+imgFile.exists(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(imgFile.exists())
 {
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}

  public String getPath(Uri photoUri) {

    String filePath = "";
    if (photoUri != null) {
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        try
        {

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        }
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Tried Solution:-

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));
```

Can anybody guide me where I'm getting wrong in displaying Image on <kbd>ImageView</kbd>?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image is not setting in ImageView with setImageURI()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158145/image-is-not-setting-in-imageview-with-setimageuri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by gnuanu, `setImageURI()` is not better to use as reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup.

Better to use the following:-

`setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.`

Still these methods didn't solve my problem. As I was taking Picture with Camera and onClick of it sending to Next Activity which may cause latency hiccups.

So better to pass to another activity after some peroid of time . .  just a  sec is totally convient to get through it.

Snippet which solve my issue:-

```
final Intent picIntent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,PicSaveActivity.class);
picIntent.putExtra("URI", pathUri.toString());
Handler handler = new Handler() 
{
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    startActivityForResult(picIntent, PICTAKEN);
    };
};
 Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
 handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000);
```

In Next Activity, catch the URI and rotate the Image as it would be in landscape mode.

```
 if(absPathUri!=null)
{
    Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absPathUri.getPath());
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(rotated);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what's wrong in your code, and my answer uses a completely different approach to taking a photo with the camera and displaying it in an ImageView, but it's a working solution that might help you.

In your first Activity (call it CameraActivity), you can do the following:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CameraActivity extends PortraitActivity {
  private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
  private ImageView imageView;
  private Bitmap photo;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
  }

  /** Method to open camera and take photo */
  public void takePhoto(View v) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
  }

  /** Method called after taking photo and coming back to current Activity */
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
      photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", photo);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}
```

In the second activity (call it NewActivity), just put the following code in the onCreate method, after having assigned `imageView` to the corresponding view in the XML layout.

```
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
      imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Comment: As I need Focus `ON` everytime a picture is taken from my application, due to that the solution which you are showing won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) clearly states: The path to the file is contained in the `Intent.mData` field.

Therefore, you need

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, absPathUri));
```

You probably also need to let the broadcast complete before you get the results; using

```
imgView.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { imgView.setImageURI(absPathUri); } }
```

should suffice.